# Escaping single quote from an MVC 3 Razor View variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, escaping

I have a variable within item.Name that contains the string "It's Tuesday!". 
To alleviate javascript errors, in the c# controller I have already escaped this single quote.
On the webpage, it appears like this "It\'s Tuesday!".

This at least prevents any javascript errors, however, I do not want the actual string displayed to contain the backslash that has escaped it.

How might I be able to revert the escaping once the javascript errors have already been taken care of?  This feels like a rather simple problem, but I am a bit unfamiliar with MVC 3.  Any hint is much appreciated!  My searching did not find me any example specific to this.

An example of my code in the Razor View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) // item.Name = "It\'s Tuesday!"
}
```

Comment: Why are you pre-escaping the quote character "to alleviate javascript errors" when there is no javascript present in your example?

Comment: It is true, there is no javascript in my example.  My example was a very basic snippet to show how the string in question I am trying to remove a backslash from is displayed in the Razor View.  There is of course javascript on the page of the actual solution.

Comment: while I am sure there is javascript on your page it still makes no sense to me why you are trying to escape a quote in a string that is intended to be rendered as HTML for a label.  I can't fathom why you are escaping it there.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Kirk, I think the only answer I have for you is that my understanding of what I am doing is on the low side - and my methods are wrong/unorthodox :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create an extension method you can use or simply encode directly. I would not encode prior to the view getting it unless you have a separate property in your viewmodel meant for this (not a bad idea()

This is not tested but something along these lines

```
public static class HtmlExtensions

{
    public static IHtmlString JavaScriptEncode(this HtmlHelper html, string item)
    {
        return new HtmlString(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item));
    }
}
```

You can then just call @Html.JavaScriptEncode(yourProperty) from the view or simply reference your encoded property name.

Comment: This method worked great, thank you! I just made an extension method to call, and then let the method remove the backspace.  While maybe not the greatest way around this issue, it did do the trick while still appeasing Javascript.

Answer (score 9):

The following can be used to prevent encoding of the output again. This does however rely on you properly dealing with it yourself.

[MVCHTMLString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx)

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(yourString)
```

Comment: I used this in conjunction with the Extension Method.  Thank you for your post!  Unfortunately I can only mark 1 answer as correct, and I cannot upvote due to low reputation.  Your time is appreciated however, for whatever that is worth!

Comment: And I really needed the boost :-)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to make my views dumb.  Therefore, I'd have a property called something like 'Display' or 'DisplayName' which handled the escaping for the view.