# Render apostrophe through MvcHtmlString.Create()

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a string which looks like: `Foo&#39;s Bazz`

I am using a custom HtmlHelper to render this text inside of a div element:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayWithReadonlyIdFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    string readonlyId = "Readonly" + helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));

    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("div");
    tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

    tag.SetInnerText(helper.DisplayFor(expression).ToString());

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Using this code, I still see the HTML representation of apostrophe, not the apostrophe itself.

I tried following the advice found in [Escaping single quote from an MVC 3 Razor View variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479260/escaping-single-quote-from-an-mvc-3-razor-view-variable) by calling JavaScriptStringEncode. I've also trying HtmlDecode. Neither have any effect.

I was wondering what I need to do to achieve rendering the actual apostrophe instead of just the HTML mark-up inside of my div element.

Comment: The ampersand character `&` appears to be encoded to its entity code `&amp;`

Comment: Why should JavaScript be tagged ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try below ?

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Some value");
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Some value");
```

**Example**

```
string value1 = "&lt;html&gt;";                 //&lt;html&gt;
string value2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value1); //<html>
string value3 = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value2); //&lt;html&gt;

MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Some value"))
```

Comment: So I had to call HttpUtility.HtmlDecode after calling tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal). If I call it for SetInnerText the tag converts it back.