# data input security and html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, security

I am working with asp.net mvc, I have a pop up modal window where a user can enter some text and it gets save to a database. This text also gets displayed on screen, read from the database.

For starters I want to ensure that no harmful tags get displayed in the database - do I need to encode/decode the input?  At present, entering alert('hello') gets saved to database and when displayed again, it shows as text - so I think I am ok but would like confirmation.

One problem, I am also taking this text when the user saves it, using javascript, adding it to a div on the page and with the text above, this does trigger the pop up alert. How can I prevent this?

I am working with different text latin, cyrillic etc so don't want any unusual characters!

Comment: **[Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16183410/2007801)**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with tags? MVC is pretty good about that type of standard validation and tends to collapse tags into `&lt;script&gt;` unless the field is explicitly marked with `[AllowHtml]`.

It is important to make the distinction that `alert('hello')` contains nothing dangerous and will go into the database just fine.

That you are directly placing this text as executable in javascript *is* an issue. What if instead of `alert('hello')` it was an ajax call, or my favorite fun test, `document.write()`. When you say you are using javascript to add the text to a div, it should not ever execute that text. Keep it as a string and ensure that you use `.toString()` on it anywhere you are worried that it is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a recursive that removes all illegal characters.  Anything that the user does not need, should be illegal.  If only letters and numbers should be used, strip out all special characters.  Make sure to apply this recursively.  After that is complete, you should [HTML encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) all of the input so that it becomes (mostly) harmless.

Don't rely on only HTML encoding to make you safe.  There are ways to defeat it, and the more layers an attacker has to contend with the more difficult it will be for him/her.

This SO question may be helpful for you with HTML encoding:  [HtmlEncode from Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144535/htmlencode-from-class-library)