# Special characters getting converted when getting it in javascript block in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting model data in javascript, it is working but the issue is if there is any single quotes or any other special characters then it is getting converted in other formats. My code is as follows:

```
 function initialize() {
        var myName = '@Model.Name';
        alert(myName);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479260/escaping-single-quote-from-an-mvc-3-razor-view-variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach is to use a JSON serializer, just like that:

```
function initialize() {
    var myName = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Name));
    alert(myName);
}
```

Now no matter how dangerous characters the `Model.Name` string contains it will be properly encoded for javascript. Also if you get some red squiggles in Visual Studio that are indicating some errors you could safely ignore those bugs in the Razor's syntax highlighter which is incapable of recognizing this perfectly valid code. Just run your application and it will work more than fine.

Comment: Use `var myName = function() { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Name))();` to avoid Visual Studio error.

Comment: @haim770, good point. I just don't want to be rewriting my code simply because Visual Studio is lacking some basic Razor intellisense support and is incapable of handling this valid syntax. What you have shown is correct javascript, but OMG, if someone is looking at the source code of your website he might be asking himself some questions :-) He would see `var myName = function() { return 'some name'}();` whereas he might expect `var myName = 'some name';`.

Comment: @haim770 Error highlighting should be a servant, not a master.

Comment: That's correct Jon, except that in the case of Razor syntax highlighting, it's not a servant, it's a crap :-)

Answer (score -1):

Use @@ to skip the @ character

```
function initialize() {
        var myName = '@@Model.Name';
        alert(myName);
    }
```